# Parse.com: ParseQuery not finding ACL'd objects (Android)

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, acl

I am trying to implement a system where users can store objects in Parse.

I am also trying to add ACLs to said objects to ensure that they are only readable/writable by a particular user.

My problem is that when I do a query, while logged in as a user, none of their ACL-restricted objects are returned.

```
ParseQuery<MyObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("MyObject");
query.whereEqualTo("owner", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<MyObject> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            //Yay!
        } else {
            //Aww...
        }
    }
});
```

The list of objects does not contain any ACL objects. The ACL for each object looks like this:

```
{
    "<user>": {
        "write":true,
        "read":true
    }
}
```

I have verified that the logged in user is the same as the ACL user.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting.

Use the data browser and Curl to verify the server state of your objects...

Should work but why not check out using a curl interface . get API key rest key from mgmt console.  Use curl to logon user(see rest docs). The response from logon call has users token.

Submit curl get on 'objectTyp' class with 3 headers(API,Rest,token). You will see your object in results.

That does not find your android SDK issue. It does clarify indirectly tho

Comment: This helped me some. Apparently my user object somehow got corrupted. I'm not sure how that happened. Deleting and recreating the user object seemed to work. Very strange.